# Seemingly identical path with one of them causing oserror

Tags: python, path

I have path A generated from an SQLalchemy query as such

```
with engine.connect() as conn:

    path_a = conn.execute(some_select_statement).scalar()
```

and path B generated by going into directories using os

```
path_b = os.path.join(main_path, user_id)
```

when I print `path_a` and `path_b`, I get an identical result from both paths

```
\\\\network_dir\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3
```

However, when I pass this path into the following function from an API library that uses `os.stat()`, I encounter error for `path_a`

```
def getFilesFromPath(list_of_path_of_dir_or_files)
    result = []

    for path in list_of_path_of_dir_or_files:
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
                for name in files:
                    full_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, name))
                    if os.stat(full_path).st_size > 0:
                        result.append(full_path)
        elif os.path.isfile(path):
            result.append(os.path.abspath(path))
```

with the error

```
OSError: [WinError 59] An unexpected network error occurred: '\\\\network_dir\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\file_name.ext'
```

where the last traceback is

```
if os.stat(full_path).st_size > 0:
```

Strangely, `path_b` works fine without any error, and when I call `os.stat()` from the terminal directly, I don't run into any error.

What is happening here?

Comment: What does `print(path_a==path_b)` produce?

Comment: The paths comparison produces ```True```.  However, the error is encountered at some file in that path ```'\\\\network_dir\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\file_name.ext'```